# Always the same problem with Conjugate

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I want to compute something like :

```
Conjugate[
 Sin[θ] (I (2 Sqrt[2] f + h[x]) + Sin[θ] η[x]) Derivative[1][h][x] + 
 ((1 + I) Sqrt[2] f (1 + I Cos[2 θ]) + h[x] Sin[θ]^2 - (Cos[θ]^3 + 
        I Sin[θ]^3) η[x]) Derivative[1][η][x]] // Refine
```

I have a list of assumptions requiring that all the quantities (also the derivatives) are `Reals` so, in principle, *Mathematica* should be able to replace the `I` by `-I`, problem is it does not...

Why is it so difficult for *Mathematica* to replace the `I` by `-I`, I really don't understand because it seems so simple...

Does anyone have a clue why it doesn't work ?

(I also tried `Simplify` / `FullSimplify` instead of `Refine` and it doesn't work as well)

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Have you tried `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: What is ` Derivative[1]` ?

Comment: The last time I tried `ComplexExpand` on a more complex expression and it didn't work but on this expression it seems to work so I will retry with `ComplexExpand` ! Thank you :)

Comment: @rhermans Try evaluating it :)

Comment: @rhermans -> It's the first derivative of h (or `\[Eta]`) with respect to `x`